# Prove that the subgroup $\langle a, b \rangle$ has order 6

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $a = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ be elements of $\mathrm{GL}_2\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)$.
>
> Prove that the subgroup $\langle a, b \rangle$ has order 6.

I can show that $\left|a\right| = 2$, $\left|b\right| = 3$, and $\left|ab\right| = 2$. By LaGrange's theorem it follows that the order of $\langle a, b \rangle$ must be a multiple of 6.

But how can I prove that $\left|\langle a,b \rangle\right|=6$?

My best idea so far is to enumerate all possible products (i.e., $e, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, \ldots$) up to redundancy and show that they generate only 6 elements.

Is there a more clever way to show this?

Hints preferred, please!

Comment: If $|ab| = \infty$, then $\langle a, b \rangle \supseteq \langle ab \rangle$ has infinite order too.

Comment: Here's a hint. I wrote out a few members of your group and found, indeed, six distinct elements. Then I made a little 6 by 6 multiplication table, filled in all the products, and confirmed that the set of 6 is closed under multiplication.  You should do the same.

Comment: $|ab|$ is not $\infty$.

Comment: @GeorgeLaw Yes, you're right. Sorry for my error.

Comment: It should be easy enough to show that $\{I, a, b, b^2, ab, ab^2\}$ are in your group.  Clearly if you multiply any of those on the right side by $b$ you get an element already accounted for.  Multiply by $a$ and $ba = ab^2, b^2 a = ab, aba = b^2, ab^2 a = b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [dihedral group of degree 3 (order 6)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6) is characterized as follows:
$$D_3\ =\ \langle \rho,\sigma \mid \rho^3=\sigma^2=e,\,\sigma\rho=\rho^{-1}\sigma \rangle$$
You have shown that $b^3=a^2=I$. It remains to show that $ab=b^{-1}a$. This will mean that the mapping $a\mapsto\sigma,\,b\mapsto\rho$ is an isomorphism from $\langle a,b\rangle$ to $D_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Groups of order 6 are either $C_6$(cyclic) or $D_6$(Dihedral). $a$ and $b$ don't commute so you just need to check $aba=b^{-1}$. i.e You only have to check one relation

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea is fairly straight forward also.

Since $|a|=2$ and $|b|=3$ you can construct the set $H=\{e,a,b,b^2,ab,ab^2\}$. Notice that each of the six element must be distinct. You can show that $H$ is subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$, and thus a group of order $6$. Now $\langle a,b\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$, and thus $\langle a,b\rangle =H$and  has order $6$.